# iPhone MapView limiting to state of Missouri only

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkmapview

I am making an iPhone app that is designed for things that will be local to only Missouri.  So my idea is to limit the map to only Missouri/regions close to Missouri.  I have the map working fine, displaying the user's location, and if they update location then the pin will also move.  Can I use something like a Custom Annotation to do this?  Or can I check the users location and decide if its withing a certain lat, long and display the map based on that?

I am working in xCode while making this project.

Comment: The app we are making is for farmers markets in Missouri, and only based off of the information about the markets in Missouri.  Therefore if your in Illinois your just looking at a map of Illinois.  Its a user friendly thing, you don't want to have to search around the map and starting zooming in and out to have to find the farmers markets in Missouri only.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do here or what you currently have working.  Is the goal to prevent the user from scrolling outside of Missouri?  If thats the case, then it has nothing to do with annotations.  Can you further specify what you want to do with a custom annotation?

Comment: Matt - I wasn't being serious - I was just making a joke as an Illinoisan - we're always making fun of Missouri and Indiana, that's all - my comment added no value to your question :)

Comment: Right now I currently have the map working.  I was trying to find a way to do just what you said, stop the user from scrolling outside of Missouri.  I just wasn't sure of the way to go about doing it.

Comment: Phooze - No offense taken so no worries. In Missouri we love to poke fun at Illinois, since there really isn't much going on there other than Chicago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the MKMapViewDelegate protocol. There are methods there that will inform you when the user's location has changed and when the map has been moved. You can then do what is appropriate depending on where the user is.

Answer (score 1):

Set the exact area that you wish to display on your map, using `MKMapView's` `region` and `centerCoordinate` properties. Then, disable scrolling and zooming using `zoomEnabled` and `scrollEnabled` of the same class.

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this. The problem is with this is that if you do want to zoom (iPhones are not very big and Missouri is fairly large on the map) that you cant.  What I ended up doing was almost like drawing a box around Missouri with latitude and longitude points and checking the MKMapView's userLocation coordinate to see if they were inside. Otherwise center the map to Columbia, MO.